# Does the throwing distance of thrown melee weapons get effected by range mods?

Tags: ps4, warframe

So, I have a Kestrel, and want it to be able to go ridiculously far on a throw. Do range mods effect how far my Tenno can throw it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Range mods only affect the melee attacks you use, not thrown projectiles.

From the wiki:

> Reach increases the range of a melee weapon's attacks, **except**
>   **Glaive(Prime) & Kestrel throws**. Reach also increases the range at
>   which Sentinels can attack enemies if installed on a Sentinel Weapon.

If you're looking to increase the throwing distance, the only choice is to build [Glaive Prime](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Glaive_Prime), which has shown in tests to have a slightly longer range than it's normal counterpart, the [Glaive](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Glaive), and the [Kestrel](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Kestrel).